My blender lights arent workings
idk why the light isn't working
I did load factory settings to help with a problem before but I don't know if that did anything. I tried using lights on other objects but it still wasn't working


Your Viewport Shading is set to Material Preview, which ignores all lights and use some world lighting.
You'll want to change your Viewport Shading to render by clicking the icon shown below. Alternatively, you can press Z and swipe up with your mouse, or Z and click on Rendered.

